# google maps refresh without displaying gray

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API v3 in javascript, and I am constantly reloading the map with an `app.get`, and adding layers and bookmarks using mongodb. To erase everything I reload the map, and while it's loading a gray background displays in the div that contains the map.

What technique do you recommend so that the gray transition is not displayed, and the map is displayed all at once?

I'm reloading the map with the following code, within the function that does the reload; if I put this code outside of the function, the new elements that arrive will appear on top. This is why I do it this way.

```
var geocoder,map
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var options = {
   zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(5.1573603, -74.982409),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
```

Comment: Google translation from Spanish improved manually; question is still unclear but I'm giving the author time to improve it.

Comment: What do you mean by _"if I put this code outside of the function, the new elements that arrive will appear on top"_?  Please clarify, and show the entire reload function for context.  The question is unclear and may be closed unless you provide much more detail.  And, Google Translate (or other online translation services) are not yet good enough to translate a question such as this to intelligible English.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. I do not speak English well. with this "if I put esta code outside of the function, the new elements will arrive That Appear on top", it means that I have a function that is updated with data from the database. The previous code is within this function. and an update, the gray background is shown in the script, because the map is updated. I do not put out of function because otherwise I do it this way, new layers and markers loaded, appear above the previous layers and bookmarks.

I do understand?

Comment: I hope my answer works for you :)

Comment: thank you very much! itself is not what I wanted, but I thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first set the `visibility` of the `div` which contains map to `hidden`; then listen to the first `tilesloaded` event, and set the `visibility` back to `visible`. Doing this the Maps should only pop up after all it tiles is loaded (so no gray screen)

Here is a quick demo which do just that:
http://jsfiddle.net/nq5t85sz/1/